# ¿Es posible solo mostrar la opción que el usuario desea sin repetir el código?

Tags: python, calculo

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de que el usuario escoja una opción y que no se tenga que repetir el código tantas veces.

Teniendo en cuenta que es finito obviamente, pero supongamos que el limite de opción es 10, y que si el usuario desea hacer la operación con 3 materias, entonces que se despliegue el código pero solo hasta el limite de 3 materias.

Hasta ahora este es el código que funciona bien, sin embargo pienso en como hacerlo de la manera que menciono y no se me ocurre nada.

```
print ("Maximo 7 materias; introduce un numero del 2 al 7\n")
    ca_ma = int (input("Escribe la cantidad de materias:"))
    while ca_ma <2 or ca_ma >7:
        print ("Recuerda, tiene que ser entre 2 a 7 materias")
        ca_ma = int (input("Intentalo de nuevo:"))
        continue
    if int (ca_ma) == 2:
        materia1 = float (input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    elif int (ca_ma) == 3:
        materia1 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia3 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°3:'))
        Creditomateria3 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°3:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1 
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        resultadocrexcali3 = materia3 * Creditomateria3 
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2 + resultadocrexcali3
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2 + Creditomateria3
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    elif int (ca_ma) == 4:
        materia1 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia3 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°3:'))
        Creditomateria3 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°3:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia4 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°4:'))
        Creditomateria4 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°4:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        resultadocrexcali3 = materia3 * Creditomateria3
        resultadocrexcali4 = materia4 * Creditomateria4
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2 + resultadocrexcali3 + resultadoxcali4
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2 + Creditomateria3 + Creditomateria4
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    elif int (ca_ma) == 5:
        materia1 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia3 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°3:'))
        Creditomateria3 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°3:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia4 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°4:'))
        Creditomateria4 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°4:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia5 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°5:'))
        Creditomateria5 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°5:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        resultadocrexcali3 = materia3 * Creditomateria3
        resultadocrexcali4 = materia4 * Creditomateria4
        resultadocrexcali5 = materia5 * Creditomateria5
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2 + resultadocrexcali3 + resultadocrexcali4 + resultadocrexcali5
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2 + Creditomateria3 + Creditomateria4 + Creditomateria5
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    elif int (ca_ma) == 6:
        materia1 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia3 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°3:'))
        Creditomateria3 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°3:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia4 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°4:'))
        Creditomateria4 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°4:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia5 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°5:'))
        Creditomateria5 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°5:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia6 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°6:'))
        Creditomateria6 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°6:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        resultadocrexcali3 = materia3 * Creditomateria3
        resultadocrexcali4 = materia4 * Creditomateria4
        resultadocrexcali5 = materia5 * Creditomateria5
        resultadocrexcali6 = materia6 * Creditomateria6
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2 + resultadocrexcali3 + resultadocrexcali4 + resultadocrexcali5 + resultadocrexcali6
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2 + Creditomateria3 + Creditomateria4 + Creditomateria5 + Creditomateria6
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    elif int (ca_ma) == 7:
        materia1 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°1:'))
        Creditomateria1 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°1:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia2 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°2:'))
        Creditomateria2 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°2:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia3 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°3:'))
        Creditomateria3 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°3:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia4 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°4:'))
        Creditomateria4 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°4:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia5 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°5:'))
        Creditomateria5 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°5:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia6 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°6:'))
        Creditomateria6 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°6:'))
        print ("\n")
        materia7 = float(input ('Digita la calificación de la materia n°7:'))
        Creditomateria7 = int(input ('Digita el credito de la materia n°7:'))
        print ("\n")
        resultadocrexcali1 = materia1 * Creditomateria1
        resultadocrexcali2 = materia2 * Creditomateria2
        resultadocrexcali3 = materia3 * Creditomateria3
        resultadocrexcali4 = materia4 * Creditomateria4
        resultadocrexcali5 = materia5 * Creditomateria5
        resultadocrexcali6 = materia6 * Creditomateria6
        resultadocrexcali7 = materia7 * Creditomateria7
        ResultadoA = resultadocrexcali1 + resultadocrexcali2 + resultadocrexcali3 + resultadocrexcali4 + resultadocrexcali5 + resultadocrexcali6 + resultadocrexcali7
        ResultadoB = Creditomateria1 + Creditomateria2 + Creditomateria3 + Creditomateria4 + Creditomateria5 + Creditomateria6 + Creditomateria7
        Resultadofinal = ResultadoA / ResultadoB
        input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
        print (Resultadofinal)
    print ("\n")  
    input ("PRESIONA ENTER PARA SALIR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque existen muchas maneras de hacer lo que dices, te pongo una y te la explicaré poco a poco:

```
print ("Maximo 7 materias; introduce un numero del 2 al 7\n")
ca_ma = int(input("Escribe la cantidad de materias:"))

ResultadoA,ResultadoB = 0,0

for n in range(1,ca_ma+1):

    materia = float(input (f'Digita la calificación de la materia n°{n}:'))
    Creditomateria = int(input (f'Digita el credito de la materia n°{n}:'))

    ResultadoA += materia*Creditomateria
    ResultadoB += Creditomateria

input ("Presiona enter para mostrar el resultado")
print (ResultadoA/ResultadoB)

print ("\n")  
input ("PRESIONA ENTER PARA SALIR")
```

En primer lugar inicias las variables `ResultadoA` y `ResultadoB` con un valor de 0.

Utilizas un bucle `for`, que irá pasando por todos los números desde el 1 hasta `ca_ma` (si no pones el +1 se parará antes de `ca_ma`).

mediante `f'.....{n}:'` pones entre las llaves el valor que tenga `n` en cada vuelta del bucle `for`.

Al poner `ResultadoX +=` lo que haces es que en cada vuelta del bucle se le sume lo que haya a la derecha del igual (`materia*Creditomateria` para A y `Creditomateria` para B).
Es lo mismo que poner `ResultadoX = ResultadoX + lo que sea`.

El resto de líneas son iguales que en tu código.